# SFML Error, undefined reference to .ttf file

Tags: c++, codeblocks, sfml

so i'm working with my first game in SFML, but I got stuck on adding font to my project.
I'm doing every step like in every tutorial, libs are linked, compiler also (basic code is working well).

This is error I'm getting: [image: error]

This is where I placed the file: [image: folder with project]

And this part of my code:

```
Font font;

if (!font.loadFromFile("digits.ttf"))
{
std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;

system( "pause" );
}
```

I'm using CodeBlocks 17.12, and SFML 2.4.2.
Any ideas how to solve it?

[image]

I think I already did all of that. It is still not working, even with simple code.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
      #import <iostream>
      int main()
    {
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");

    sf::Font font;

    if (!font.loadFromFile("arial.ttf"))
    {
        //dada
    }

    sf::Text text;
    text.setFont(font);
    text.setString("Hello");
    text.setColor(sf::Color::Red);
    text.setCharacterSize(20);


    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(text);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not about the ttf file. You're getting a linker error, most likely because you forgot to link your executable to the sfml-graphics library (and it's dependencies).

So you'd have to add at least the following dependencies as libraries to link against (it's in your project settings):

- sfml-graphics
- sfml-window
- sfml-system

Comment: Already did that, I think.
Or maybe I don't see something obvious.